# Updating Google Storage object metadata without full access

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to update the metadata of an object in Google Storage when using an OAuth2 authentification token with read/write (but not full) access to the bucket?

My naive attempts (HTTP PUT with `x-goog-copy-source` set to the same object, and 
`x-goog-metadata-directive: REPLACE`) fail with an `AccessDenied` error. gsutil seems to have the same problem:

```
$ gsutil config -r -w 
[...]
$ echo hello > foo.txt
$ gsutil -h "x-goog-meta-foo: bar" cp foo.txt gs://nikratio-test/
Copying file://foo.txt [Content-Type=text/plain]...
Uploading   gs://nikratio-test/foo.txt:                          0 B/6 B    
$ gsutil stat gs://nikratio-test/foo.txt
gs://nikratio-test/foo.txt:
    Creation time:      Sun, 09 Nov 2014 22:34:22 GMT
    Content-Language:   en
    Content-Length:     6
    Content-Type:       text/plain
    Metadata:
        foo:         bar
    Hash (crc32c):      NT3Yvg==
    Hash (md5):     sZRqySSS0jR8YjW00mERhA==
    ETag:           CID8ka7K7sECEAE=
    Generation:     1415572462272000
    Metageneration:     1
$ gsutil setmeta -h "x-goog-meta-foo: com" gs://nikratio-test/foo.txt
Setting metadata on gs://nikratio-test/foo.txt...
AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden
```

I presume this is because the setmeta operation would also allow me to change the ACL of the object.
However, it seems to me that if I'm able to delete the object and re-upload it with different metadata using the same authorization, then there really ought to be a way to just change the metadata as well.

Answer (score 2):

Setting metadata works with OAuth2. I suggest running this gsutil command and comparing the protocol output it generates with what you're doing:

gsutil -o GSUtil:prefer_api=xml -d setmeta -h x-goog-meta-data-00:gAJ9cQBYBQAAAGFwcGxlcQFYCAAAAHBvdGF0b2VzcQJzLg gs://your-bucket/your-object

Comment: The problem is not with using OAuth2, it is with OAuth2 and read/write (but not full) access to the bucket. gsutil suffers from the same problem, it works only if the auth token has full access.